# SQL select rows having several values in common

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem to select some articles rows depending on a condition.

Here's my problem : All my articles can have several 'tags' attached, so my structure looks like this :

```
articles       articles_tags       tags
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯       ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯       ¯¯¯¯
  id           article_id          id
  title        tag_id              name
  content
  [...]
```

Now I'd like to select ALL articles which have BOTH tags 2 and 3 for example. I tried this :

```
SELECT * FROM articles a
JOIN articles_tags at
    ON (a.id = at.article_id)
WHERE
    at.tag_id IN(2, 3)
GROUP BY article_id
```

But this will select all articles which have AT LEAST tags IDs #2 or #3 (seems logic after all)

Is there any trick or something to get only the articles having a defined list of tag IDs ?

Thanks you

Comment: Do you want those articles having tags 2 and 3 and possibly others, or only those articles having tags 2 and 3 and no others?

Comment: Yes, and possibly the others too. Sorry I didn't precise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is called `Relational Division`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    articles a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT at.article_id 
            FROM   articles a
                   INNER JOIN articles_tags at
                      ON a.id = at.article_id
            WHERE  at.tag_id IN(2, 3)
            GROUP  BY at.article_id
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
        ) b ON a.id = b.article_id
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Works on fire ! Thank you, I didn't know this had a name.
Btw, it's
    ON a.id = b.article_id ;-)